# How do I mock a class with easymock 3.x?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, easymock

So I've got the following import in my class:

```
import static org.easymock.classextension.EasyMock.*;
```

So I create a real object

```
SomeJobDataMap map = SomeJobDataMap();
map.put(Constant.SOMETHING,"somevalue");
map.put(Constant.SOMETHING_ELSE,"anothervalue")
```

Then I create a mock:

```
SomeJobContext context = createMock(SomeJobContext.class);
expect(context.getJobDataMap()).andReturn(map);
```

replay(context);

```
testTargetClass.methodUnderTest(context);
```

... no errors except the NPE that occurS when "methodUnderTest" tries to access the values. Why isn't my mock returning the map?

Comment: try adding `verify` and make sure you have mocked the right method (i.e. it is invoked in the flow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your class under test is collaborating with your SomeJobContext class.
In that case you need to call testTargetClass.setContext(context).

Comment: This was quite a while ago but as I recall, I had forgotten to call replay();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgotten to configure the number of times the test expects the method to be invoked?

```
SomeJobContext context = createMock(SomeJobContext.class);
expect(context.getJobDataMap()).andReturn(map).once();
replay(context);

testTargetClass.methodUnderTest(context);
```